# "TypeError: (0 , _Dummy.default) is not a function" when running Jest unit test with Vue Composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have created a simple Vue 2 application using the Vue Composition API with Typescript and I am separating my logic into Composition Functions in separate typescript files. Everything works just fine when I run the application, but when I try to run Jest unit tests against the component I get the following error:

*TypeError: (0 , _Dummy.default) is not a function*

I have replicated the issue in a simple dummy setup with the following Dummy.vue component:

**Dummy.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>Test</p>
    <p>{{ isLoading }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "@vue/composition-api";
import useDummy from "./Dummy";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Dummy",
  setup(props, { root }) {
    const { isLoading, IsLoading2 } = useDummy();
    //return { isLoading, IsLoading2 }; //It doesn't make a difference if I return or not
  },
});
</script>
```

This is importing and using the Dummy.ts composition function with the `useDummy()` call above. The Dummy.ts can be seen below:

**Dummy.ts**

```
export default function() {
  const isLoading: boolean = false;
  const isLoading2: boolean = false;

  return { isLoading, isLoading2 };
}
```

The Jest unit test that fails is this:

**Test.spec.ts**

```
import "jest";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import CompositionApi from "@vue/composition-api";
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import Dummy from "@/components/Dummy/Dummy.vue";

const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(CompositionApi);
localVue.use(Vuex);

describe("Dummy", () => {
  it("should not fail mounting", () => {
    var wrapper = shallowMount(Dummy, {
      localVue,
    });
  });
});
```

I have isolated the issue to occurring when I call the composition function `useDummy()`. If I comment this line out the test succeeds. Similarly if I take the code from the composition function and embed it directly in the Dummy.vue component it works as well.
Interestingly, if I remove the use of `localVue` it also goes through, but I guess that it because it then doesn't know to use Composition API and therefore doesn't call the setup() method. So that is not really an option.